# MFC menu is not drawing but white blank

Tags: menu, mfc

Im working on some Window Customizing stuff.
I removed title bar and border of CFrameWnd and added my own title bar.
It seems work nice.
But if I add menu to this window, menu will be on top of this window. (above my title bar)
So I add new CFrameWnd and set my menu to this new CFrameWnd.
this is the code.

```
CMenu * pMenu = this->GetMenu();
if( pMenu != NULL )
{
    this->SetMenu(NULL);

    m_pMenuWnd = new CMenuWindow();
    m_pMenuWnd->Create(NULL, NULL, 0, m_WindowRects.MenuRect, this, 0, NULL);
    m_pMenuWnd->SetMenu(pMenu);
    m_pMenuWnd->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
}
```

And I added this menu window's move handler on my custom CFrameWnd's OnSize, OnMove Message Handler for corrent positionning.

It looks pretty good.
But when I minimize and restore its position, menu windows position is just white blank.

But if I move cursor on there, menus r there.
What am I doing wrong?
I checked OnCtlColor but its not even get called.

Here's CMenuWindow code

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMenuWindow, CFrameWnd)
ON_WM_CREATE()
ON_WM_ACTIVATE()
ON_WM_KEYUP()
ON_WM_SYSKEYUP()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CMenuWindow::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
CRect clRect;
GetClientRect(&clRect);
}

// CMenuView message handlers
int CMenuWindow::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
if (CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
    return -1;

ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION, WS_CLIPCHILDREN);
ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What type of object is CMenuWindow?  It appears like it's a CWnd.  If so, what does it's code look like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. CMenuWindow is derived from CFrameWnd.